# core data - how to use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to build an app that uses core data, but all the tutorials I found in the net didn't show if I can store a data without using the code it self.

Is there anyway to do it?

For example, i want to make a row of name and put there couple of names.

Comment: You realize Core Data is all in code? You can't do anything with Core Data without writing any code.

Comment: May be this will help you.
[check this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)

Comment: and there is nothing that i can use in objective c that it is like sql for example? that i can add info without code?

Comment: If you're going to "build and app that uses core data," you will by definition be writing code, so it's hard to understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just read the book ["Pro Core Data for iOS"](http://apress.com/book/view/1430233559) from APRESS it covers Core Data very well. I recommend this by heart.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/).  But it's not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite directly without Core Data; there you'd have your SQLs in your own hands. Your can use Core Data and debug SQLs issued by the framework, of course if using SQLite as the store.

Core Data works also with binary and XML format (the latter not available on iPhone): passing following argument to the application:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

Other than that, you could probably use SQL to access Core Data SQLite store, since it is all SQL, but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Core Data is all code. However, CoreData is an api that helps you create, save, load data from the database, it uses SQLLite in an easier fashion.

If you need very complex data storage then by all means use SQLLite directly. But, if it's just simple data storage of names, emails, booleans, etc, then i would recommend CoreData.

I'll give you a link that it helped me greatly when i wanted to integrate CoreData for my app.

[CoreData Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Good Luck.